# Grouped bar plot with multiple labels in x-axis

Tags: bar-chart, gnuplot

I am trying to replicate something close to the following graph in gnuplot as I need to use it on a latex paper. I have tried a lot but I cannot make the two-line labels at the bottom. Could you please guide me? Also, how is it possible to have the % character as part of a label in the x-axis? Latex complains about it.

[image]

The data are in the following format (example). Each different color corresponds to different method. Blue is method 1 (m1), orange is method 2 (m2), and brown is method 3 (m3)

```
#%      system1-m1  system1-m2  system1-m3  system2-m1  ...
0.5%    16          8           15          6
1%      15          17          16          8
2%      12          10          20          15
```

Thanks

**Edit**

My code so far is as follows:

```
set rmargin 0
set key outside tmargin center top horizontal width 3
set border
set grid
set boxwidth 0.8
set style fill solid 1.00 
set xtics nomirror rotate by 0
set format y '%1.f'
set yrange [0 to 22]
set ylabel 'Gain (\%)'
set ytics 0, 5

set style data histograms

set label 1 at -0.3, -4 '|---------System 1------------|'
set label 2 at 2.7, -4 '|---------System 2------------|'

plot "./data/metrics.dat" using 2:xtic(1) title 'Method 1' ,\
     "" using 3 title 'Method 2', \
     "" using 4 title 'Method 3',
```

And I have modified the .dat file as

```
0.5 16  8   15
1.0 15  17  16
2.0 12  10  20
0.5 13  6   4
1.0 11  13  13
2.0 14  12  14
```

because I cannot make it print the % character. The output graph is

[image]

As you can see it is not scalable. I have to put labels by hand (trial and error) and also the labels below the x-axis do not contain the % character.

Comment: What exactly have you tried so far? Could you please show your (non-)working code?

Comment: I have updated the post with my code. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for providing the code. I would try `set format x '%.1f\%'`, but I cannot test right now.

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not work. I also tried `set format x "%g%%" `, but still nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've been close: `set format x '%.1f\%%'`. The following works for me with `cairolatex` terminal (check `help cairolatex`).

**Code:**

```
### percent sign for tic label in TeX
reset session

set term cairolatex
set output 'SO70029830.tex'

set title 'Some \TeX\  or \LaTeX\ title: $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$'
set format x '%.1f\%%'

plot x

set output
### end of code
```

**Result:** (screenshot)

[image]

**Addition**:

Sorry, I forgot the second part of your question: the labels.
Furthermore, in your graph you are using `xtic(1)` as tic labels, i.e. text format, so the command `set format x '%.1f\%%'` from my answer above will not help here. One possible solution would be to create and use your special TeX label like this:

```
myTic(col) = sprintf('%.1f\%%',column(col))
plot $Data using 2:xtic(myTic(1))
```

For the labels, I would use arrows and labels. Each histogram is placed at integer numbers starting from `0`. So, the arrows have to go from x-values `-0.5` to `2.5` and from `2.5` to `5.5`. The labels are placed at x-value `1` and `4`. There is certainly room for improvements.

**Code:**

```
### tic labels with % for TeX and lines/labels
reset session
set term cairolatex
set output 'SO70029830.tex'

$Data <<EOD
0.5 16  8   15
1.0 15  17  16
2.0 12  10  20
0.5 13  6   4
1.0 11  13  13
2.0 14  12  14
EOD

set rmargin 0
set key outside center top horizontal width 3
set border
set grid
set boxwidth 0.8
set style fill solid 1.00 
set xtics nomirror rotate by 0
set format y '%1.f'
set yrange [0 to 22]
set ylabel 'Gain (\%)'
set ytics 0, 5

set style data histograms
set bmargin 4

set arrow 1 from -0.5, screen 0.05 to 2.5, screen 0.05 heads size 0.05,90
set label 1 at 1, screen 0.05 'System 1' center offset 0,-0.7
set arrow 2 from 2.5, screen 0.05 to 5.5, screen 0.05 heads size 0.05,90
set label 2 at 4, screen 0.05 'System 2' center offset 0,-0.7

myTic(col) = sprintf('%.1f\%%',column(col))

plot $Data using 2:xtic(myTic(1)) title 'Method 1' ,\
     "" using 3 title 'Method 2', \
     "" using 4 title 'Method 3',
set output
### enf of code
```

**Result:** (screenshot from LaTeX document)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the answer of @theozh there is already a build-in function called `newhistogram` that directly allows to place labels below the x-axis.

While working on an an answer that involves `newhistogram` I discovered a bug with horizontal key layout, which is now fixed thanks to Ethan. So, with the newest development version of gnuplot at hand I am able to offer a solution that allows for more finetuning like the ability to change the inter-group spacing.

```
set terminal cairolatex standalone colour header '\usepackage{siunitx}' size 25cm, 7cm 

# generate some random data in your format
N = 7
set print $MYDATA
do for [i=1:N] {
    print sprintf('0.5 %f %f %f', rand(0)*20, rand(0)*20, rand(0)*20)
    print sprintf('1.0 %f %f %f', rand(0)*20, rand(0)*20, rand(0)*20)
    print sprintf("2.0 %f %f %f", rand(0)*20, rand(0)*20, rand(0)*20)
}
unset print

# define the look
set style data histograms
set style fill solid 1.00
set boxwidth 0.8
set key horizontal outside t c width 1

set xr [-1:27]
set xtics nomirror
set ytics out 5 nomirror
set grid y                # I don't think vertical grid lines are needed here
set ylabel 'Gain/\%'
set rmargin 0.01
set bmargin 3
```

As for the tic marks, I adapted @theozh's answer a bit – since you are using LaTeX already, you might as well parse the numbers through `siunitx`, which will ensure correct spacing between numbers and the unit:

```
myTic(col) = sprintf('\SI{%.1f}{\%}',column(col))
```

The vertical separation marks like in the screenshot you provided can be created iteratively:

```
do for [i=1:N+1] {set arrow i from first -1+(i-1)*4, graph 0 to first -1+(i-1)*4, screen 0 lw 2 nohead}
```

Now for the actual plot command:

```
plot newhistogram "System 1" offset 0,-0.5 lt 1, for [i=1:3] $MYDATA using (column(i+1)):xtic(myTic(1)) every ::0::2 title sprintf('Method %.0f',i), \
newhistogram "System 2" offset 0,-0.5 lt 1 at 4, for [i=1:3] $MYDATA using (column(i+1)):xtic(myTic(1)) every ::3::5 not, \
newhistogram "System 3" offset 0,-0.5 lt 1 at 8, for [i=1:3] $MYDATA using (column(i+1)):xtic(myTic(1)) every ::6::8 not, \
newhistogram "System 4" offset 0,-0.5 lt 1 at 12, for [i=1:3] $MYDATA using (column(i+1)):xtic(myTic(1)) every ::9::11 not, \
newhistogram "System 5" offset 0,-0.5 lt 1 at 16, for [i=1:3] $MYDATA using (column(i+1)):xtic(myTic(1)) every ::12::14 not, \
newhistogram "System 6" offset 0,-0.5 lt 1 at 20, for [i=1:3] $MYDATA using (column(i+1)):xtic(myTic(1)) every ::15::17 not, \
newhistogram "System 7" offset 0,-0.5 lt 1 at 24, for [i=1:3] $MYDATA using (column(i+1)):xtic(myTic(1)) every ::18::20 not
```

That looks very nasty, what's going on here?
`newhistogram` creates a new group of histogram boxes, its first argument is a string that is put below the x axis. It is also told to reset the linetype counter to 1.
Then the three columns of the data are plotted iteratively, but not all lines at once, but only the first three lines, with corresponding key entries.
Then another newhistogram is created and it is told to start at the x value 4 (which would be the default anyway). Now the next three lines are plotted, and so.

Now, every time `newhistogram` is called an empty line is added to key, hence making trouble with the key placement. Therefore the new keyword introduced by Ethan is

```
set style histogram nokeyseparators
```

which will disable this behaviour.

[image]

As you see, the spaces between the groups are larger than inside. You might want to change the numbers in `newhistogram at ...` and adjust the calculation of vertical line positions accordingly.

The plot command is of course highly repetitive, and it would be nice to make it an iterative call. Unfortunately, iterations that span multiple objects are not possible within a `plot` call. However, it is possible to iteratively put the plot command string together (excessively using string concatenation `.`) and then plot it.

```
A = 'newhistogram "System '
B = '" offset 0,-0.5 lt 1'
C = 'for [i=1:3] $MYDATA using (column(i+1)):xtic(myTic(1)) every ::'
myplotstring = A.'1'.B.', '.C."0::2 title sprintf('Method %.0f',i),"

do for [i=2:N] {myplotstring = myplotstring.A.i.B.'at '.(4*(i-1)).', '.C.(3*i-3).'::'.(3*i-1).' not, '}

plot @myplotstring
```